# Does ColdFusion use TCP Ports?

Tags: firewall, ip, tcp, coldfusion, port-80

I am trying to access [a link](http://info.gladstonerc.qld.gov.au/forms/tenders/availableTenders.cfm) on our network.

Whenever I try, the page times out. I have discovered that this link is a Adobe ColdFusion web page.

Does ColdFusion use a TCP port other than port 80? I suspected that I have a Firewall issue however, I do not really know a lot about ColdFusion.

I can access the above link on other networks without problem however, in our network it does not work on any computer. I have tried both IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion is a platform/language. It is not in and of itself a web server, application layer protocol or network protocol. ColdFusion based websites run on whatever TCP port the website itself is running on, typically ports 80 or 443. HTTP/HTTPS operate at the application layer over TCP, not UDP.